# Enable APR(Apache portable Runtime) in jboss 6.2 eap on windows

Tags: windows, jboss, websocket, jboss-eap-6, apr

I just want to enable atmoshpere websocket support in jboss 6.2 eap. so i googled and found this link 
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Installing-JBoss-WebSocket-Support

As this link suggest, i am trying to enable APR in jboss
and i have downloaded jboss native library from follwing link for my system(windows 64 bit)

http://jbossweb.jboss.org/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-9.html

And i have extracted this to my jboss and added the path to java_opts

set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.library.path=D:\jboss-eap-6.2\bin\native"

then Started the server

But still its not working, i never find the log saying "[AprLifecycleListener] Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.20."

And i  got the following error

00:05:38,220 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http-/127.0.0.1:8087-1) Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.JBossAsyncSupportWithWebSocket, error: JBoss failed to detect this is a Comet application because the APR Connector is not enabled. 
Make sure atmosphere-compat-jboss.jar is not under your WEB-INF/lib and You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
there is no context.xml under WEB-INF Is the NIO or APR Connector enabled?
00:05:38,220 ERROR [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http-/127.0.0.1:8087-1) If you have more than one Connector enabled, make sure they both use the same protocol, e.g NIO/APR or HTTP for all. If not, org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport will be used and cannot be changed.: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBoss failed to detect this is a Comet application because the APR Connector is not enabled. 
Make sure atmosphere-compat-jboss.jar is not under your WEB-INF/lib and You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
there is no context.xml under WEB-INF

Please help me to enable  APR(Apache portable Runtime) in jboss 6.2 eap on windows. i am newbie to jboss.